# Append a list of strings to first column in a csv

Tags: python-2.7, list, csv

I have a list of lists in the following format:

```
test_data = [[0.09792, 0.04583, 0.01667, 0.05208, 0.02917, 0.0375, 0.03958, 0.11042, 0.03542, 0.01667, 0.13125, 0.01667, 0.01875, 0.04583, 0.1, 0.05833, 0.06042, 0.00625, 0.03333, 0.04792], 
            [0.0709, 0.04104, 0.0398, 0.06343, 0.02239, 0.03109, 0.07463, 0.04851, 0.01493, 0.05597, 0.11194, 0.0597, 0.04104, 0.03731, 0.02612, 0.0995, 0.05224, 0.00373, 0.02985, 0.07587], 
            [0.1232, 0.0704, 0.0128, 0.056, 0.024, 0.032, 0.0528, 0.0656, 0.0256, 0.0384, 0.1088, 0.0368, 0.0352, 0.0352, 0.0688, 0.0528, 0.0336, 0.0096, 0.0384, 0.08]
```

This is just a subset of the complete data that contains more sub-lists. I use the following code to write the data to csv as follows:

```
import csv
import sys
with open("my_data.csv", "wb") as my_csv:    
    w = csv.writer(my_csv, sys.stdout)
    w.writerow(column_headers)
    w.writerows(zip(*test_data))
```

The "column_headers" variable is a list of strings, 24 elements long, that is written as the first row to serve as column identifiers. It has the format:

```
column_headers = ['header_1', 'header_2', ....., 'header_24']
```

The output csv table looks like this:

```
header_1,  header_2,  header_3, ...., header_24
0.0979,    0.0709,    0.1232,   ...., 0.0688
0.0458,    0.0410,    0.0704,   ...., 0.0527
0.0166,    0.0398,    0.0128,   ...., 0.0389
```

I want to add a list of strings as a new first column, that will represent row ids, so that the table format is as follows:

```
row_id = ['row_id', 'a', 'b', 'c'...., 'k']

row_id,  header_1,  header_2,  header_3, ...., header_24
a        0.0979,    0.0709,    0.1232,   ...., 0.0688
b        0.0458,    0.0410,    0.0704,   ...., 0.0527
c        0.0166,    0.0398,    0.0128,   ...., 0.0389
```

I use the following code to do this:

```
for ind, line in enumerate(fileinput.input("my_data.csv", inplace = True)):
    sys.stdout.write("{},{}\n".format(line.rstrip(), row_id[ind]))
```

Unfortunately the data comes out in a different format. The list of strings is placed in the last column. It looks like this:

```
    header_1,  header_2,  header_3, ...., header_24,  row_id
    0.0979,    0.0709,    0.1232,   ...., 0.0688,     a
    0.0458,    0.0410,    0.0704,   ...., 0.0527,     b
    0.0166,    0.0398,    0.0128,   ...., 0.0389,     c
```

How can i adjust the above code to place row_id in the first column as desired?

Thanks for your time

Comment: did you try this ```sys.stdout.write("{},{}\n".format(row_id[ind], line.rstrip()) ```

Comment: @rishabh.bhardwaj that simple. Thanks!

Comment: @rishabh.bhardwaj, would you mind posting your answer, even if it that simple. I would like give your response the up-vote. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply swapping the order of 2 arguments! Credit to @rishabh.bhardwaj in comments for my original post. See below:

```
for ind, line in enumerate(fileinput.input("my_data.csv", inplace = True)):
    sys.stdout.write("{},{}\n".format(row_id[ind], line.rstrip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for ind, line in enumerate(fileinput.input("my_data.csv", inplace = True)):
    sys.stdout.write(f"{row_id[ind]},{line.rstrip()}\n")
```

Comment: Hello Sari, thanks for the suggestion. I adjusted as follows (must be a typo):                {for ind, line in enumerate(fileinput.input("my_data.csv", inplace = True)):
    sys.stdout.write("{row_id[ind]},{line.rstrip()}\n")}                                                         It's almost there, however this string "{row_id[ind]}" is also printed very other line.

Comment: Hi i'm not sure how to format code snippets in comments. My comment looks a little messy. Any advice would be great. Thanks

Comment: Great, Nice to hear that, For formatting code in the comment: use this character {\`}  before and after the code  => \`code \`  : `code`

Answer (score 0):

```
sys.stdout.write("{},{}\n".format(row_id[ind], line.rstrip())
```

Comment: this answer came in Low Quality posts in SO.... Could you add any commentary to your answer? Explain your logic, and give a little commentary on what your code is intended to do. This will help the OP, but it will also serve as commentary for future users